# Ajax can't send data to php as json without error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I want to send data as datatype json it response this error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

When I tried to send the data as datatype text, it sends the data to php successfully but my php wont respond.

ajax/js as datatype json:

```
let form = $("#form");

$("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
                          
  e.preventDefault();
                          

  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
       test: 1
    },
  success: function (r) {
    console.log("!!!");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);
  }
  });

});
```

ajax/js as datatype normal:

```
let form = $("#form");

$("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
                          
   e.preventDefault();
                     
   $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function (r) {
        console.log("!!!");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
   });

});
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST["test"])){
   echo "<script>console.log('works');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Well `<script>console.log('works');</script>` is simply _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: I deleted this echo script. The error is the same, but now "at position 2".

Comment: Well then your script must still be responding with something, that isn’t valid JSON. First of all, check what the response actually was, using your browser dev tools (network panel.)

Comment: damn, why is the content-type: text/html... any solution? or is this not the issue?

Comment: _“damn, why is the content-type: text/html”_ - did you even say it should be anything else anywhere to begin with? And what is the actual content of the response body you got?

Comment: `dataType` sets the Data Type for the **response** Object, so your ajax call expects a json object back from your PHP, but you echo some `<script>` String. try something like `echo json_encode(['myVar' => 'myValue']);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ob = {
       test: 1
    };
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data:JSON.stringify(ob),
  success: function (r) {
    console.log("!!!");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);
  }
  });
```